# Serving a large dataset with minimal bandwidth

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, geojson, mapbox-gl-js, mbtiles

I want to serve a large spatial dataset, preferably without webgl support, over minimal bandwith. I've seen many examples doing so. For example:

- https://interaktiv.morgenpost.de/europakarte/

What would be the best way to achieve something like this? Is it possible without hosting my data on mapbox, maybe host the data on AWS S3? How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. There's a technology called an UTFGrid, which are tiles in JSON format. These tiles can be generated in many ways, for example by using TileMill and MB-util. These tiles are very small, but enable the user to see featureinfo on hover. Once these tiles are generated they can be hosted anywhere you want, AWS S3 or your own web-server.